# How to prove this expectation equality?

Tags: probability, measure-theory, probability-theory

[image]
How to prove this expectation equality? I am studying probability theory by myself and I find it hard. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First assume that $X$ is nonnegative. Let $I_n$ be the indicator function for $\bigcup_{k=0}^n A_k$. Then
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n E(X;A_k)=\int_{\cup_{k=0}^n A_k} X(\omega)dP(\omega)=\int_\Omega I_n(\omega)X(\omega)dP(\omega).
$$
The first equality above uses the disjointness of the $A_k$'s. The sequence $\{I_nX\}_n$ is increasing and converges to $I_AX$ where $I_A$ is the indicator for $A$. So you can apply the Monotone Convergence Theorem to infer that
$$
\lim_n \sum_{k=1}^n E(X;A_k)=\lim_n \int_\Omega I_nXdP=\int_\Omega(\lim_n I_nX)dP=\int_\Omega I_AXdP=\int_AXdP=E(X;A).
$$
For more general $X$, apply the result above for to the RHS of $X=X^+-X^-$.